# How to read a text file from Internal Storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been working on a project witch my file has been saved in internal storage. And I have watched multiple videos on how to read a file. But nothing has helped me read a file under this directory. Here is all the java code that I got so far.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text_box;
Button b_show;

float x1,y1,x2,y2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    b_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);
    text_box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    b_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = "";
            try{
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("Scores.txt");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                text = new String(buffer);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            text_box.setText(text);
        }
    });
}


public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent) {
    switch(touchEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = touchEvent.getX();
            y1 = touchEvent.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = touchEvent.getX();
            y2 = touchEvent.getY();
            if(x1 < x2) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no code there for reading a file. You have code for reading an asset. "I have been working on a project witch my file has been saved in /data/data/myapp/files/" -- then your app must have code for writing that file. What are you using for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out sorta. Instead of using Inputstream as the base of it. I used File Inputstream and InputStreamReader. Here is the code for the entire @override to help.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = "";
            try{

                FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("Scores.txt");
                InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

                char[] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
                String s = "";
                int charRead;

                while((charRead = InputRead.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                    String readstring = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                    s += readstring;
                }
                InputRead.close();
                text_box.setText(s);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```